Reliable transaction confirmations
Our backend service is sending transactions to solana but we are having trouble with transaction confirmations. We were running into Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found errors regularly so we added a retry mechanism (of course with a new blockhash). We also came across this: https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions/confirmation#be-wary-of-lagging-rpc-nodes-when-sending-transactions which suggests to keep sending a transaction in a regular interval.
Our current implementation looks something like this:
async function send(connection: web3.Connection, instructions: web3.TransactionInstruction[], signer: web3.Keypair) {
    for (let i = 0; i < MAX_RETRIES; i++) {
        const priorityFee = calculatePriorityFee(i, instructions.length)

        const priorityFeeInstruction = web3.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
            microLamports: priorityFee,
        });
        
        const blockhashResponse = await connection.getLatestBlockhash({
            commitment: "confirmed"
        })
        
        const recentBlockhash = blockhashResponse.blockhash

        const message = new web3.TransactionMessage({
            payerKey: signer.publicKey,
            recentBlockhash: recentBlockhash,
            instructions: [priorityFeeInstruction, ...instructions],
        }).compileToV0Message();

        const transaction = new web3.VersionedTransaction(message);
        transaction.sign([signer]);
        
        // Re-send transacion to rpc every 2 seconds until it either gets confirmed or the blockhash expires
        while (true) {
            try {
                const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction)

                await sleep(2000)

                const statusResponse = await connection.getSignatureStatus(signature)
                const status = statusResponse.value?.confirmationStatus

                // Success
                if (status === "confirmed" || status === "finalized") {
                    return signature
                }
            } catch(err) {
                console.error(err)
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}

Note: This is not our exact implementation but this is in essence what we are currently doing.
With all this we still run into Blockhash not found errors regularly. On some days up to 30% of our transactions fail with this error.
Are we doing something fundamentally wrong?
We are passing up to 5 instructions to the send function, does the size of the transaction matter?
We also use Helius, does the RPC provider make a difference?
Is there anything we can do to submit a large amount of transactions in a reliable way?

why we are re-sending every two seconds, does block hash expires in 2 seconds?

This suggests to keep sending transactions to the rpc

This is perfectly correct. If the blockhash expires and the transaction hasn't landed, you can certainly fetch a new blockhash, sign the transaction again, and keep trying to send. The only other thing you can do is set a compute unit limit to go with the price. If the transaction declares a lower limit than the default, then the leader may be able to pack it at the end of a block.

@ashish0411 were you ever able to find a solution?

since message is blockhash not found, try to debug if you are getting blockhash or not. in some case blockhash rpc fails resulting in adding null as blochhash,

if blockhash rpc fails, try adding retry in blockhash rpc
